# Trouble understanding Variational Inference objective

Tags: random-variable, evidence-lower-bound, variational-inference

I was reading the [Meta Temporal Point Processes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.12023.pdf) paper and was having trouble understading the training objective presented. The authors state that it is the ELBO used in Variational Inference techniques.

[image: The ELBO training objective]

where $L$ is the number of observations, $\tau_{l}$ is a continuous varaible observed $l$th, and $z \sim p_{\theta}\left(z | \mathcal{C}_{L}\right)$ according to the paper, where $C_{l}$ is defined as $\left\{ \tau_{t-k+1:t} \right\}_{t=1}^{l-1}$.

However, the above expression is very confusing, and I have three questions.

1. $p_{\theta}$ is defined as the distribution of $z$, however, it is used as the distribution for $\tau$ as well?
2. Why is $p_{\theta}\left(\tau_{l}\right)$ not $0$ given that $\tau$ is a continuous variable?
3. Why did $\tau_{l+1}$ in the first term become $\tau_{l}$ from $(6)$ to $(7)$?